# How to full an array vertically by infinite 1D array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array, stack

I apply sliding window on a (22x921600) matrix where each window of size (1x7680). Now I want to create 2D array using this 1D array (1x7680) to be concatenating vertically.

I am trying for more than 2 weeks to find how I can do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**code**:

```
data=np.random.rand(22, 921600)
S=0
_SIZE_WINDOW=30*256
new_array=[]
    t=0
    movement=int(S*256)
    if(S==0):
        movement=_SIZE_WINDOW        
    while data.shape[1]-(t*movement+_SIZE_WINDOW) > 0:
        for i in range(0, 22):
            start = t*movement
            stop = start+_SIZE_WINDOW
            window=data[i,start:stop]
            new_array=np.append(new_array,window)
         t=t+1
```

Comment: please provide expected output for explicitly specified input. Please provide values of `_SIZE_WINDOW`, `S`, `data` to let someone else run your code. Otherwise people will start downvoting your question

Comment: @tstanisl  done. Data is a matrix of size(22x921600).

Comment: is `t` ever updated?

Comment: @tstanisl Yes after each movement

Comment: `S` is zero. So is `movement` always equal to `_SIZE_WINDOW`?

Comment: @tstanisl yes exactly

Comment: ok.. So tell me what is the problem with your code? is it too slow? is it incorrect?

Comment: @tstanisl the output is matrix of size (7656960,) but it should be (50,7680) or may be number of rows will be bigger than 50 and number of columns should be 7680.I want to be apended vertically (rows each others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do no use `np.append`. Just append the slice of array to the list and stack all entries vertically at the very end with `np.vstack`.

The code (after some editing):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(22, 921600)
_SIZE_WINDOW = 30*256
new_array = []
t = 0
movement=_SIZE_WINDOW
while t * movement + _SIZE_WINDOW <= data.shape[1]:
    for i in range(22):
        start = t * movement
        stop = start + _SIZE_WINDOW
        window = data[i, start:stop]
        new_array.append(window)
    t += 1

# stack all windows vertically
new_array = np.vstack(new_array)

print(new_array.shape) # prints (2640, 7680)
```

BTW. This while operation could be done in O(1) by fancy reshaping or with help of [as_strided](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html). However this solution is similar to code in the question.